# Create a mini database in Closure from a txt file

Tags: clojure

I am really new to clojure and im having trouble with the following;

I am trying to read data from a txt entry that can have strings in this format:

```
1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533
```

I figured out how to read and split the data with the following code

```
(with-open [reader (clojure.java.io/reader "cust.txt")]
  (vec (for [line (line-seq reader)] ; iterate over each line
         (->> (clojure.string/split line #"\|") ; split it by "|"
              (remove empty?)
                (zipmap[:custID :name :address :phoneNumber]))))) ; turn into a map
```

The issue is with this zipmap, I am having trouble accessing individual values like custID.

```
(get zipmap :custID)
```

The code above returns nil

How should I change my code so that I can access a customer's data?

Comment: If `zipmap` is a row from above code, this works just fine. Please show
us the actually not working problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not name the return variable `zipmap` as it's a reserved function name. Let's call it `ret`.

`ret` is a vector of maps. You can't `(get ret :custID)`, which is why you are getting `nil`. If you want all the custID, use `(map :custID ret)`. Or maybe you want to index your vector by custID, in which case create `(def ret2 (zipmap (map :custID ret) ret))` and then you can easily find the second entry with `(get ret2 2)`.